# Go.Gorm - Запрос для количества

Tags: golang, gorm

У меня есть проблема с получением количества записей по следующему SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT da.id, da.* 
FROM delivery_area AS da 
LEFT JOIN delivery d on da.id = d.delivery_area_id 
WHERE (da.merchant_id = ?) AND (d.delivery_area_id IS NULL)
```

Когда я добавляю .Count у Gorm.DB после составления запроса выше, то он преобразовывыает это в

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM delivery_area AS da 
LEFT JOIN delivery d on da.id = d.delivery_area_id 
WHERE (da.merchant_id = ?) AND (d.delivery_area_id IS NULL)
```

Хотя по документации видно что в Count будет значение из Select, а не просто *. Это баг, или я не так составляю запрос к Gorm?

**Приведенные выше SQL запросы это результат .Debug()**

Comment: Ну судя по результату - не так составляете что-то. *Хотя по документации видно что в Count будет значение из Select* - второй запрос однозначно НЕ даёт никакое значение из первого SELECT. Какое, кстати, значение Вы ожидаете? надеетесь, что количество записей, возвращаемых первым запросом? однозначно нет.

Comment: Ожидаю получить COUNT(DISTINCT da.id), либо просто обертку над этим запросом в форме SELECT COUNT(SELECT ... мой запрос выше). Проблема тут в том что я не могу использовать SubQuery как параметр для составления Raw запроса чтобы включить его там в виде Gorm.Raw(`SELECT COUNT(?)`, subQuery).Scan(&total) потому что что здесь он пишет что ожидает структуру.

Comment: *Ожидаю получить COUNT(DISTINCT da.id)* Облом. `da.*` в списке вывода не оставляет надежд, если имеются полностью совпадающие записи. Впрочем,  если в таблице таки есть хотя бы один уникальный индекс (скажем, первичный), то это просто фреймворк - тупой.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov добавьте в вопрос строки кода на gorm. вы всегда можете читать не в структуру, а в свою переменную. Count так и работает. `var count int64
db.Model(&User{}).Where("name = ?", "jinzhu").Or("name = ?", "jinzhu 2").Count(&count)`